# Deklinieren von Titeln von Büchern und Filmen

Tags: usage, article, declension, proper-noun

Ist Deklinieren von Titeln von Büchern und Filmen im Deutschen üblich? Denn in meiner Sprache würde ich einen Titel deklinieren, wenn das möglich ist.

Zum Beispiel im Quizduell vom 9. März (Das Erste, Mediathek) kam die Frage:

> Die deutsche Synchronstimme von Chuck Norris in "Walker, Texas Ranger" gehört auch zu...?
>
> - SpongeBob Schwammkopf
> - Benjamin Blümchen
> - Samson aus der "Sesamstrasse"
> - Willi aus "Die Biene Maja"

Hier ist der Unterschied das die “Sesamstrasse” den Titel ohne Artikel hat und “Die Biene Maja” mit Artikel.

Trotzdem möchte ich fragen: Ist das für Deutschsprecher leicht so zu sagen:

> **aus die Biene Maja**

**Bricht das nicht irgendetwas im Sprachgefühl? Und ist das früher (vor hundert Jahren) auch so gewesen?**

---

```
Nachdem die Frage als "duplicate" markiert ist
```

Ich habe die Frage bold markiert. Es tut mir so leid, dass niemand mich versteht. Muss ich glauben, dass "aus die" verstößt gar nichts gegen das Sprachgefühl? Umgekehrt - ihr alle wärt empört, wenn jemand (ich) "aus der" gesagt hätte?

Apropos, wie ich es schon oben schreibe, diese Frage hat entstanden, wenn ich in einer Sendung gehört habe, wie in einem Satz zwei Kinderserien erwähnt worden sind - eine mit "aus der" und die andere mit "aus die".

Und nicht umsonst habe ich um "früher (vor hundert Jahren)" gefragt. Aber ok, lassen wir es, sowieso weiß keiner von euch es. Entschuldigung.

Comment: Das Markieren einer Frage als Duplikat bedeutet nicht, dass die Frage schlecht ist. Es bedeutet auch nicht, dass wir die Frage nicht verstanden hätten. Und schon gar nicht bedeutet es, dass wir sie nicht beantworten können. Es bedeutet schlichtweg nur: Genau dasselbe hat schon ein anderer vor dir gefragt, und diese Frage wurde bereits beantwortet.

Comment: Die Frage nach dem Sprachgefühl ist off-topic (primarily opinion-based), weil das von den einzelnen Meinungen abhängt und nicht allgemeingültig beantwortet werden kann. Nach meinem Sprachgefühl passt das, was du da im Fernsehen gehört hast, perfekt. Da klingt nichts falsch.

Comment: @hubert-schölnast na ja, eher eine Umfrage

Answer (score 0):

Eigennamen werden im Deutschen normalerweise nicht dekliniert. Das gilt auch für Artikel, Pronomen und Adjektive, die in Eigennamen auftauchen.

Beim Schreiben setzt man solche Eigennamen mit Artikeln usw. mit Anführungszeichen ab, oder man druckt sie anders, meist in Schrägschrift. Beim Sprechen macht man vor dem Eigennamen eine Pause und betont den Namen wie bei der Einleitung der direkten Rede. Man kann alternativ auch ein erklärendes Nomen verwenden, dann braucht man die Pause nicht.

> In *<DOPPELPUNKT>* »Die Biene Maja« geht es um…
>
> In der Kindersendung »Die Biene Maja« geht es um…

Comment: Eigennamen werden sehr wohl dekliniert. _Das ist Jörg**s** Buch_. Hier steht Jörg im Genitiv, weshalb ein Es angehängt wird.

Comment: Das Genitiv-s ist eine der wenigen Ausnahmen und es klappt nur bei Einzelwörtern. Schon *Das ist »Die Biene Majas« erste Folge* kann man nicht sagen, selbst ohne den Artikel klänge es komisch.

Comment: Man kann ohne weiteres '*Das ist die erste Folge der "Biene Maja"* ' schreiben und soll es laut Duden "richtiges und gutes Deutsch" auch. Wenn du unbedingt auf deine leicht schräge Wortreihenfolge bestehst, geht '*Das ist der "Biene Maja" erste Folge*'. Dein Satz hört sich so komisch an, weil du den Titel falsch dekliniert hast.

Comment: Der Titel ist nicht *Biene Maja*, sondern *Die Biene Maja*.

Comment: @Janka Das ist richtig. Aber: Du möchtest, glaube ich, das verlinkte Duplikat lesen, und dort meine Antwort oder den Link auf den Duden. Es gibt ziemlich genaue Regeln, wie man solche Titel flektiert. Eine davon ist, dass man flektierte Artikel vor das Zitat zieht

Comment: @Janka Dass man "aus der Kindersendung »Die Biene Maja«" sagen kann, verstehe ich selbst.

Comment: @tofro Also, "das ist die »Biene Majas« erste Folge" geht nicht? Und "das ist der "Biene Maja" erste Folge" geht einigermaßen?

Comment: @Andra "Die Biene Majas erste Folge" geht nicht, aber aus einem Grund, der mit Titeln eigentlich gar nichts zu tun hat. In Substantivpaaren, die nach der Form "Artikel + Ding + Name" gebildet werden, wird im Deutschen das "Ding" dekliniert und nicht der Name: "Die Krone *des Königs* Karl" statt "Die Krone des König *Karls*" und "das Wasser *des Sees* Genezareth" statt "das Wasser des See *Genezareths*". (Das ist im Englischen anders: King George's Bible") Daher ist dein zweites Beispiel (besser mit umgekehrter Wortreihenfolge) *Die erste Folge der "Biene Maja"* vollkommen richtig.

Comment: Leider sieht man der "Biene" hier nicht an, das sie Genitiv ist. Aber sie ist's

Comment: @tofro Ich glaube, es kann mir passieren, dass ich sowas wie "die nächste Biene Majas Folge" und sogar "die nächste In aller Freundschafts Folge" sage. Äußerst unakzeptabel?

Comment: Man versteht wohl, was du meinst. Falsch ist es trotzdem.

Comment: @tofro Man würde aber auch "die Krone König Karls" sagen, was "König Jacobs Bibel" entspräche. Ansonsten stimmt es schon.

Comment: @Chieron Da steht ja auch  "Artikel+Ding+Name" - Dein Beispiel entspricht nicht dieser Form - "König" hat keinen Artikel. Ansonsten stimmt es schon ;)